# Cannot resolve symbol R when move class out of default package

Tags: android, android-studio

When my "ExampleAdapter" class is in the sample package as my MainActivity, I don't get an error. Let's say my MainActivity is in "com.example". When I create a new package inside of the "com.example" package (let's say "com.example.adapters"), and move my "ExampleAdapter" to the new package, I get the dreaded error, "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'". Why does it matter which package my adapter is in?

Comment: Are you updating your `package` import at the top of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it matter which package my adapter is in?

The `R` and `BuildConfig` classes are always code-generated into the Java package that you name in the `package` attribute of your `<manifest>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Any Java classes outside of that package that need to refer to `R` or `BuildConfig` need to add the corresponding `import` statement, as with any other Java class from a foreign package.